# How to change Samsung M283x printer favorites order

Tags: windows, printer

I have a Samsung M283x printer and for some reason it trys to printer to the last settings that were printed. Last thing I printer was a label from a Dymo label printer and then it prints my documents really small the size of the label. There is a setting that says "last used settings" and it is checked. You cannot delete the setting from Favorites or lower it in the list

http://www.samsungsetup.com/ts/manual/Samsung%20M288x%20Series/English/manual/img/w_12.png

That link is the picture of the menu I see

Answer (score 0):

This is normally application dependent. Some apps will always go back to the printer's settings In Devices and Printers. Other apps will keep the last settings used in that app. Apps like Word save some printer settings (paper size and type) with the document, so that, when you re-open the document, you get the last saved settings.

In your case however, it appears to be a driver "feature". The fact that you cannot deselect "Last used settings" seems to imply that you are printing via a server. In that case, you must change the setting on the server. Do this by going to Devices and Printers (on the server) > Printer Properties > Advanced tab > Printing Defaults button. After you change it there, go to Printing Preferences and, if necessary, change it there as well.

After this change, the users will see the new selection when they print.